# Excel VBA: When I remove a row, have my numbered list update

Tags: vba, excel

I have data starting in row A8, where A is filled down with numbers increasing by 1 each row. I'm running into an issue where if I delete a row, those numbers are now out of order (Ex: 1,2,3,5). I want my macro to be able to update those numbers if I end up deleting a row of data. I have a worksheet change sub that does a few other things once a change is made, so I was thinking of adding this part to the end of that.

Any help would be great.

The full macro is way too long, but here:

```
If Target.Cells.Count > 1000 Then

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Worksheets("Testing Sheet").Range("H2").Value = "" Then
        Worksheets("Testing Sheet").Range("H2").Value = "SKU " & Worksheets("Detailed SKU List").Cells(Target.Row, 2).Value & " deleted on " & Date
    Else
        Worksheets("Testing Sheet").Range("H1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Value = "SKU " & Worksheets("Detailed SKU List").Cells(Target.Row, 2).Value & " deleted on " & Date
    End If
    Worksheets("Testing Sheet").Range("H1").End(xlDown).Font.Size = 8
    Worksheets("Testing Sheet").Range("H1").End(xlDown).Interior.Color = rgbLightBlue

    'Updates the row numbers


    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub

End If
```

Comment: There's a thing in Excel where you can tell it to fill a column with increasing numbers, and you don't need a macro to do it.  Basically, this cell equals one more than the one above it.  It will automatically update when you delete a row, since it's just a calculation.

Comment: Well I want it to automatically do it after my actual macro runs. This way the user doesn't have to do it manually @RobertHarvey

Comment: This is a programming website, not an Office website.  Post your macro, so we can have a look at it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I didn't want to post the macro because it isn't very related to my problem. I wanted this to be an addition to my already made macro. I knew I could manually do this, but I asked my question specifically to make it easier for people to use.

Comment: Complete with a blank spot where you want us to insert the code.  Well...

Comment: @RobertHarvey I asked the question because I don't know how to do it. That the point of me asking the question. I want someone to put me in the right direction

Comment: Why can't you just have a calculated column?

Comment: Because if all of those columns change, the macro becomes never ending. It's a worksheet change macro, therefore, if you change a cell, the macro will run. What you are proposing will have the macro run when it doesn't need to.

Comment: What I am proposing is to have a column that's auto-generated.  The user will never change it.

Comment: Wouldn't it still trigger the macro though? The cells themselves are changing, so even though the user didn't change it, it would effectively trigger the macro anyway. I'm not sure if that is true but just wondering.

Comment: Your macro runs on the change of any cell in the spreadsheet?  Are you sure that's a good idea?  Preventing infinite loops is going to be very difficult.

Comment: I think I've worked out most of the kinks in it, but what I have is if any cell is changed, I have a few things about that cell documented, like the date it was changed, the old value, the new value the user has implemented, etc. The part of code I have above makes sure it doesn't do the entire macro if the user selects more than 1000 cells, but I could edit that if need be. It seems to work when I delete an entire row, but then those numbers I am trying to increment are out of order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As is stated in the comments, I'm not a big fan of doing things the way you're proposing they be done, but the code to do it would be as follows:

```
' Set the cells starting at A8 and all the way down to "ROW-7" (since you start at row 8, it starts at 1 and continues onward)
Worksheets("Testing Sheet").Range(Worksheets("Testing Sheet").Range("A8"), Worksheets("Testing Sheet").Range("A8").End(xlDown)).FormulaR1C1 = "=ROW()-7"

' Convert the formula to a value
Worksheets("Testing Sheet").Range(Worksheets("Testing Sheet").Range("A8"), Worksheets("Testing Sheet").Range("A8").End(xlDown)).Value = _
    Worksheets("Testing Sheet").Range(Worksheets("Testing Sheet").Range("A8"), Worksheets("Testing Sheet").Range("A8").End(xlDown)).Value
```

It's long, but that's because I'm referencing the `Worksheets("Testing Sheet")` a few times per line of code.

Hope this does the trick!